# ADMM quadprog R

Tags: r, quadprog

To implement the ADMM optimization, I try to use quadprog. The equation I want to minimize is

```
`min x^T*S*x + 1(x) + lambda^T*(x-z) + rho/2*||x-z||²`
```

quadprog minimize a function under the following format

```
`min -d^T*b + 1/2*b^T*D*b`
```

after developping my function I do have something like this

```
`min x^T*C*x + lambda^T*(x-z) - rho*x*z + rho/2*z² + 1 - lambda^T*z`
```

So I can set quadprog parameters, I have 
     `Dmat = S + diag(rho/2)` and `dvec = rho*z - lambda`. But I do have  constant values: `rho/2 * z² + 1 - lambda*z` that remains!

How can I add this to the quadprog function ?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

The constant term does not have any meaning for the minimization itself. Just leave it off, find the optimal point with quadprog and, if you like,
add the constant to the value at the minimum.